# How to properly set the allow and deny for apache 2.4 conf and vhosts

Tags: apache, vhosts, apache2.4

I need some advice on how to properly setup the vhosts file directives preferably without changing the apache2.conf contents. This is for apache 2.4.

Currently, I get `AH01797: client denied by server configuration` probably caused by the `Require all denied` in the apache2.conf.

**apache2.conf:**

```
<Directory />
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
```

**vhosts file:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.example.com
        ServerAlias sub.example.com
        <Directory /var/www/sub.example.com>
                AllowOverride None
                Allow from all
                Require all granted  
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
Adding this to the `apache2.conf` works, it just doesn't work in vhosts file. Any idea why?

```
<Directory /var/www/sub.example.com>
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2.4, you shouldn't use Order, Deny, or Allow at all. Purge them and replace with Require.

> UPDATE Adding this to the apache2.conf works, it just doesn't work in vhosts file. Any idea why?

Maybe the vhosts file isn't included in your configuration, or mod_ssl is not loaded so the whole thing is commented out? The IfModule doesn't make much sense here.